# Using curl library in DosBox

Tags: curl, dosbox

I have a task to develop some application providing SOAP-requests realization for DOS. I have already developed a similar application under Linux, using C++/STL and curl and openssl libraries. Is there any way to use such method in my environment now? The environment is DosBox and open watcom compiler. Could you tell me is it possible to have an access to the Internet and send SOAP-request to remote server from DosBox? What I should do for that? Now the “ping” command is illegal…http://screeny.ru/5331846bad32b5dc4003be04 Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have a similar problem